# Hibernate : map field with condition without foreign key

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following structure to store data for tracking devices (reduced complexity to simplify) in a MySQL database.

I use Hibernate to handle this data in a web application.

---

*Tables structure*

**tag**
`id`
`name` (string)
`last_tag_detail_id` (foreign key on tag_detail table)

**tag_detail**
`id`
`tag_id` (foreign key on tag table)
`date` (UTC date)
`lat` (gps latitude, may be null if no GPS position)
`lng` (gps longitude, may be null is no GPS position)

---

*Problem*

I have a requirement that when I retrieve a tag, I should get the last tag_detail (which I have thanks to the `tag_detail_id` foregin key).

Now I also have to get the most recent tag_detail with a valid GPS position (latitude and longitude != null).

Is it possible to do so with Hibernate annotations without having to add a `last_tag_detail_gps_id` foreign key in the `tag` table ?

For now I have the following mapping :

**Tag class**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "mac")
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "last_tag_detail")
private TagDetail lastTagDetail;
```

**TagDetail class**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", nullable = false)
private Tag tag;

@Column(name = "lat")
private BigDecimal latitude;

@Column(name = "lng")
private BigDecimal longitude;

@Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime date;
```

Is it possible without adding a foreign key in the `tag` table to add a `lastTagDetailWithGPS` field in the Tag class, which would retrieve the last TagDetail by date which have a non null latitude and longitude ? If so, what would be the proper Jpa or Hibernate annotation to do so ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You say you wanted to:

> retrieve the last TagDetail by date which have a non null latitude and
>   longitude

I don't think you need to add an additional foreign key to your `tag` table, since in your `Tag` entity you already have a reference to a `TagDetail` entity mapped as one-to-one. In your JPA query, you can just simply traverse to your `TagDetail` entity and check on the values of its properties: `latitude`, `longitude` and `date`.

Here's your JPA query:

```
SELECT td FROM Tag t INNER JOIN TagDetail td
WHERE td.date = :date AND
td.latitude IS NOT NULL AND
td.longitude IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Il looking for a hibernate annotation

Comment: There's a `@Where` annotation, but it only applies to collection valued relationship.

Comment: What do you mean by 'collection valued relationship' ? Does that mean I can't use a Where annotation to do that in the end ?

Comment: Per Hibernate documentation, `@Where` can only be used on a class level. But if you are going to apply the annotation on a field of your entity class, then it must be a collection-valued relationship. Anything annotated with `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` is a collection-valued relationship. While `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` associations, are called single-valued relationship. So in your case, `@Where` won't apply since you have used `@OneToOne` mapping.

Comment: So, I guess I'm going to need this foreign key field